# oracle function for: select distinct values count from comma separated string

Tags: oracle, function, distinct, distinct-values, csv

I need an Oracle (11) function to handle this question.
I need to counting distinct values count from comma separated string.

For example the comma separated string:
'Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text'

The result have to be = 6

Beacuse of

1. Lorem
2. Ipsum
3. is
4. simply
5. dummy
6. text

I want to use like this

```
select fn_dist_count_values_in_list_arr('Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text') from dual;
```

Can anyone help to write this ("fn_dist_count_values_in_list_arr") oracle function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a context switch from SQL to a PL/SQL function and can do it all in SQL:

```sql
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT CAST(column_value AS VARCHAR2(20)) )
         FROM   XMLTABLE( ('"'||REPLACE(value,',','","')||'"') ) )
         AS num_distinct_values
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | NUM_DISTINCT_VALUES |
> | ------------------: |
> |                   6 |
> ```

If you want a pure PL/SQL function (so that you do not have multiple context-switches) then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_dist_count_values_in_list_arr (
  list_value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  TYPE t_words IS TABLE OF NUMBER(1,0) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(200);
  v_words t_words;
  v_start PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  v_end   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF list_value IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  LOOP
    v_end := INSTR( list_value, ',', v_start );
    EXIT WHEN v_end = 0;
    v_words(SUBSTR(list_value, v_start, v_end - v_start ) ) := 1;
    v_start := v_end + 1;
  END LOOP;
  v_words(SUBSTR(list_value,v_start)) := 1;
  RETURN v_words.COUNT;
END;
/
```

and then:

```sql
SELECT fn_dist_count_values_in_list_arr( value )
FROM   table_name
```

outputs:

> ```
> | FN_DIST_COUNT_VALUES_IN_LIST_ARR(VALUE) |
> | --------------------------------------: |
> |                                       6 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f20ba39fb694e242bee3b1cdbcfacf0)*

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DIST_COUNT_VALUES_IN_STR_ARR
    (STR_ARR IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
    AS
    DIST_COUNT NUMBER(38);
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) 
        INTO DIST_COUNT FROM (
            SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR_ARR,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) COL1 
            FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(STR_ARR, ',') + 1
        );
        RETURN DIST_COUNT;
    END;
```

This worked for me. The inner query separates the elements into rows by using regex on the comma character. I had to rename your function as i hit the limit of the max length of an object name for my version of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

And another approach would be to use hierarchical query to split comma separated values to a set of rows (with clause) and run a simple sql query against it

```
with str_parsed as (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) val
                    FROM dual
                    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text,Lorem,Ipsum,is,simply,dummy,text', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
select count(distinct val) from str_parsed
```