# Is there an easy way to get the max number from a String in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, numbers, delimited

I have a database field that contains a string of numbers like 50,40,60,10,0,4
is there any easy way to determine the highest number in the sting other than iterating thru the string and comparing values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle function for: select distinct values count from comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546471/oracle-function-for-select-distinct-values-count-from-comma-separated-string) . Just replace the "COUNT" with "MAX"

Answer (score 0):

If you guarantor if exists just numbers on field you can use function MAX(TO_NUMBER()).

Example:

```
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(user_registration)) FROM USER;
```

If you want to remove the caracteres you can use REGEXP_REPLACE to use just the numbers: REGEXP_REPLACE(seu_campo, '[^0-9]', '').

```
SELECT MAX(REGEXP_REPLACE(user_registration, '[^0-9]', '')) FROM USER;
```